# Unable to pass jwt token in header in swagger UI in GO

Tags: go, jwt, swagger, go-swagger

Unable to pass the JWT token in the header in the Swagger UI.Have tried API, its working fine.

Below is the code snippet for CORS

````
    handleCORS := cors.Default().Handler
    return handleCORS(handler)
}```


Used the below codes for swagger in the respective handler
```// consumes:`enter code here`
// -application/json
// swagger:parameters getticket3
type ticketsParams2Wrapper struct {
    // Get ticket by id
    // in: path
    // required: true
    //type:application/json
    ID string `json:"id,omitempty" bson:"id,omitempty"`
    // an authorization header


    // in:header
    // required: true
    // type:string
    Token string
````

[Below is the screenshot of the issue occurring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pc3q6.png)

Comment: It looks like you need to add `Token` to the allowed headers list for CORS.